# Clang++ Environment Error in Mac

Tags: c++, macos, clang, environment, clang++

I use mac and clang as my default compiler. Someday someone was accidentally deleting one of my libraries and causing my environment crashed... Now when I execute clang++, a lot of error information appears on my terminal, saying:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdlib:101:9: error:

          no member named 'div_t' in the global namespace
    using ::div_t;
          ~~^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdlib:102:9: error:
          no member named 'ldiv_t' in the global namespace
    using ::ldiv_t;
          ~~^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdlib:104:9: error:
          no member named 'lldiv_t' in the global namespace
    using ::lldiv_t;
          ~~^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdlib:106:9: error:
          no member named 'atof' in the global namespace
    using ::atof;
          ~~^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdlib:107:9: error:
          no member named 'atoi' in the global namespace
    using ::atoi;
          ~~^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdlib:108:9: error:
          no member named 'atol' in the global namespace
    using ::atol;
          ~~^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/`c++/v1/cstdlib:110:9: error:
          no member named 'atoll' in the global namespace
    using ::atoll;
```

And it sum up to 50 errors!
What I want to ask is, if there is a way to recover the clang environment without reinstall the system? I just don't know exactly where these functions are...

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting Xcode.app from your Applications folder, empty the trash, then reinstall it from the App Store.

Comment: I have done it, but still unable to recover... It is so frustrating. Maybe my dependencies missed...